# Как пишется дополнение к ТЗ?

Tags: проектирование

Допустим у меня есть раздел 2, и пункт 2.3. Требования к СУБД и там будут пункты:

- а) СУБД должна быть быстрой;
- б) СУБД должна иметь возможность резервного копирования и восстановления данных;
- в) СУБД должна ставиться на Linux;

Прошел год. И заказчик захотел модернизировать систему. И написал еще требования. Одно из них пусть будет "СУБД должна быть бесплатной". И потребовал все требования и дополнения оформить в виде дополнения к старом ТЗ.

В ГОСТ сказано:

> 3.6. Титульный лист дополнения к ТЗ на АС оформляют аналогично титульному 
> листу технического задания. Вместо наименования «Техническое задание» пишут 
> «Дополнение № ... к ТЗ на АС … ».
>
> 3.7. На последующих листах дополнения к ТЗ на АС помещают основание для 
> изменения, содержание изменения и ссылки на документы, в соответствии с которыми 
> вносятся эти изменения.
>
> 3.8. При изложении текста дополнения к ТЗ следует указывать номера 
> соответствующих пунктов, подпунктов, таблиц основного ТЗ на АС и т.п. и применять 
> слова: «заменить», «дополнить», «исключить», «изложить в новой редакции».

Но тут всё не понятно.
Я пишу дополнение так:
Раздел 2. Пункт 2.3.
Дополнить: г) СУБД должна быть бесплатной

Или я переписываю весь (под)пункт полностью? Т.е:

2.3. Требования к СУБД

- а) СУБД должна быть быстрой;
- б) СУБД должна иметь возможность резервного копирования и восстановления данных;
- в) СУБД должна ставиться на Linux;
- г) СУБД должна быть бесплатной

Answer (score 3):

Исходя из цитаты из ГОСТа, правильнее

> Раздел 2. Пункт 2.3. Дополнить: г) СУБД должна быть бесплатной

Да и исходя из здравого смысла тоже, если вы пишете дополнение, то должно быть сразу ясно, что именно изменилось. Как вариант можно (наверное) написать так:

> Раздел 2. Пункт 2.3. Дополнить: г) СУБД должна быть бесплатной
>
> Таким образом:
>
> - 2.3. Требования к СУБД
> - а) СУБД должна быть быстрой;
> - б) СУБД должна иметь возможность резервного копирования и восстановления данных;
> - в) СУБД должна ставиться на Linux;
> - г) СУБД должна быть бесплатной

Comment: Дополнение в виде "Как вариант" (т.е. с повтором содержания пункта в новой редакции) выглядит более привлекательно (с т.з. разработчиков ПО).